# Null pointer dereference of 'object' where null comes from condition in Android

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer, nullreferenceexception

Following class I use to create a MediaPlayer object and. This works fine

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class PatientAlarm {

    private static MediaPlayer md ;

    private PatientAlarm() {
    }

    private PatientAlarm(Context context) {
        md = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.patient_alarm);
        md.setLooping(true);

    }

    public static MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer(Context context) {
        if (md == null) {
            new PatientAlarm(context);
        }
        return md;
    }

    public static void startMediaPlayer(Context context) {
        if (md == null) {
            new PatientAlarm(context);
            md.start();
        } else {
            if (!md.isPlaying()) {
                new PatientAlarm(context);
                md.start();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void stopMediaPlayer(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        if (md == null) {

        } else {
            if (md.isPlaying()) {
                md.stop();

            }
        }

    }

}
```

But the problem is Klocwork analyzer says

**NPE.COND: Null pointer dereference of 'md' where null comes from condition : Java : PatientAlarm.java : Critical (1) : Analyze : Local**

That occurs in below line

```
md.start();
```

I have no idea what it does mean. before start md, I check whether it is null.

Please guide me to make my code more reliable and how to solve this issue,

Answer (score 2):

You totally messed up the concept of Object Oriented Programming. 
You defined `PatientAlarm` class to incapsulate all logic of working with `MediaPlayer`. It's OK.

But why did you make all methods static? Why `new PatientAlarm()` called inside these methods and created instance even not assigned to some variable or field that makes it target for garbage collection?

This is example of how you should do it:

```
public class PatientAlarm {
    private MediaPlayer md;

    public PatientAlarm(Context context) {
        md = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.patient_alarm);
        md.setLooping(true);
        md.prepare();
    }

    public void start() {
        if (!md.isPlaying()) {
            md.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (md.isPlaying()) {
            md.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Adapt it to your case and read more about using `MediaPlayer` class.

Answer (score 0):

which md.start(); line? there are 2... anyway your code is totally vulnerable for  concurrency issues, you may read about locks to prevent it, but I would start form refactoring, before you get into advanced stuff. Creating a new object just to initialize a static member of the class is probably the most ugly approach for singleton I have ever seen.. If you really need to, use static method to do it for you, at least there wont be a new object for GC to collect. But in fact the use of static object in your example seems to be a miss first of all. Try rewriting it without static fields or methods and most likely your code will be simpler and more reliable.